# Behat / Mink Opens Blank Page in Browser

Tags: bdd, behat, mink

I'm using Behat and Mink on Ubuntu for BDD. I've three steps in my feature:

```
Given I am on "/control.php"
And I wait for "3000"
Then print last response
```

If I do not include the @javascript tag, the test completes successfully and prints the correct HTML.

If I include the @javascript tag, the web browser (firefox) opens to a blank tab and Behat prints three blank lines instead of the actual HTML.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, I found that an error in the javascript caused the browser to alert a notice (visible in console). This notice caused Behat / Mink to trip and end execution. Hope this is helpful!